# Canonical way to stop boost::asio operations

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost-asio

I have a `boost::asio::io_service` running in a thread that performs some operation:

```
struct clicker
{
    clicker(boost::asio::io_service& io) : timer_(io) { wait_for_timer(); }

    void stop() { timer_.cancel(); }

    void wait_for_timer()
    {
        timer_.expires_from_now(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
        timer_.async_wait(std::bind(&clicker::wait_completed, this, _1));
    }

    void wait_completed(const boost::system::error_code& err)
    {
        if (!err) {
            std::cout << "Click" << std::endl;
            wait_for_timer();
        }
    }

    boost::asio::steady_timer timer_;
};

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io;
    clicker cl(io);

    std::thread io_thread(&boost::asio::io_service::run, &io);

    while (true) { // the run loop
        // gather input
        if (user_clicked_stop_button()) { cl.stop(); break; }
    }

    io_thread.join();
}
```

Now calling `stop()` should cancel waiting for the timer and fire `wait_completed()` with an error. However, we have a race condition here: at times, `stop()` will be called while `wait_for_timer()` is running and before the `async_wait` has been scheduled. Then, the code will run indefinitely.

What's the recommended way to deal with this situation? A boolean flag inside `clicker` that is tested in `wait_completed`? A mutex?

### Update:

This is just a simplified example, in the real code I have several operations running in the `io_service`, so calling `io_service::stop()` is not an option here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post the action to the io_service thread:

```
void stop() 
{ 
  timer_.get_io_service().post([=] { timer_.cancel(); }); 
}
```

(If your compiler is not c++11-compatible, use `bind` to create the lambda.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to call [io.stop()](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service.html) to stop the io_service object.

Comment: This is just a simplified example. I want the other operations to continue.

Comment: ahh, I missed that.  In that case post the cancel operation to the io_service. io.post(boost::bind(&clicker::stop, cl));